# AH00111: Config variable ${DocumentRoot} is not defined

Tags: apache-2.4

I am running Apache 2.4 X64 from ApacheLounge on 3 Windows 10 machines. Machines 1 & 2 work properly. Machine 3 is a new installation. If I try "localhost:index.html" it works properly, but if I try "localhost:/DD/index.php", I get the AH00111 error in the Apache log and n HTTP 500 error in the browser. The PHP.INI files are all the same. Likewise for HTTPD.CONF. Machine 2 is using PHP 7.07 and machine 3 is using PHP 7.2.8.

BTW:

- phpmyadmin & phpinfo both work properly.
- The "DD" sub-directory is a Drupal website (same version as on the other 2 machines).
- There are no virtual hosts

Answer (score 0):

When copying the Drupal files, using FTP, several files and some folders did not get transferred. Transferring those files , re-running Drupal "install.php" and doing "update.php" fixed the problem.

I hope this helps someone else in the future. Drupal's error messages gave some help, indicating where things were going bad, but didn't have anything about "missing" files. There were 2 messages about "cannot get filename of non-object...".